# Wordpress - create a post with a table based on data from MySQL view

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

On my WordPress site I would like to have a post that includes a table based on data from a MySQL view (the view is on the same database as my MySQL install). Are there any plugins that can do this? I noticed there is a plugin called TablePress but that seems to only show data from a static table. I found the Insert PHP plugin which I think can help me here but I don't know how to reference the view inside my WordPress database?

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Thank you.

Comment: Is it a custom MySQL table?

Comment: Yes it is a custom view and not part of the original Wordpress schema

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb#SELECT_Generic_Results

The codex explains how to very easily get the database object and how you can manipulate the results.

---

**EDIT -> Explain returns further**

Say you have the following MySQL table:

```
|id        |fname     |sname     |age       |
-----------------------------------------------------
|1         |Dan       |White     |28        |
|2         |Bob       |Smith     |24        |
|3         |Lisa      |Roberts   |31        |
|4         |Steve     |Stevens   |22        |
```

And you want to echo it out as-is, you would:

```
 $myQuery = $wpdb->get_results( 
    "
    SELECT * 
    FROM table_name
    ORDER BY id ASC
    "
);
if($myQuery){
echo '<table>';
foreach ( $myQuery as $result ) 
    {
        echo '<tr><td>'.$result->id.'</td><td>'.$result->fname.'</td><td>'.$result->sname.'</td><td>'.$result->age.'</td></tr>';
    }
echo '</table>';
}
```

Comment: Thank you Daniel! But I am missing a basic concept here - where does this query from your link go? It doesnt mention if this can get placed in a post/page?

Comment: Hi. Use this as the first step of your script, i.e. extract the data object and simply echo out the results (in a <table> if necessary).

Comment: Thank you for the quick follow-up! But which script are you referencing? Do you mean the single.php template file?

Comment: Updated my answer. Place it wherever you want to display the table or if you are planning to use it more than once, put in functions.php and return the output instead.

Comment: Alternatively, you can use a WordPress plugin like twiganything.com that lets you input your MySQL query and HTML template for output, and then use a shortcode to render it anywhere, e.g. [twig-anything slug="data1"].

Comment: So promoting lazy, incompetent "development" then @Meglio? Why on earth would you use a plugin for something so insanely basic? Plugin = bloat. In nearly every case, a plugin used to do something ridiculously basic will inevitably slow down the site.

Comment: @DanWhite using plugins does not mean incompetency.

Comment: In this case, yes, it does. Not by the OP, but the person recommending it. It is not a good recommendation. In fact, it's a harmful one. You would be giving any admin user, with an unknown level of expertise in this area access to shortcodes that allow for direct database connectivity, without filter from the database. Where should I begin on why that is a very, very bad idea?